# PySpark Exploding array<map<string,string>>

Tags: arrays, dictionary, pyspark, explode

I am trying to explode a column in the format array<map<string,string>>. Using PySpark in DataBricks.
Data looks like:

```
root
 |-- zipcode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employment_status: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

```
sdf:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
zipcode:string
employment_status:array
element:map
key:string
value:string


+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|zipcode|employment_status                                                                                                                            |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|95678  |[[key -> Data, values -> [{x=Full-time, y=13348}, {x=Part-time, y=8918}, {x=No Earnings, y=9972}]]]|
|95679  |[[key -> Data, values -> [{x=Full-time, y=0}, {x=Part-time, y=29}, {x=No Earnings, y=0}]]]         |
|95680  |[[key -> Data, values -> [{x=Full-time, y=43}, {x=Part-time, y=0}, {x=No Earnings, y=71}]]]        |
|95681  |[[key -> Data, values -> [{x=Full-time, y=327}, {x=Part-time, y=265}, {x=No Earnings, y=278}]]]    |
|95682  |[[key -> Data, values -> [{x=Full-time, y=8534}, {x=Part-time, y=6436}, {x=No Earnings, y=8748}]]] |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have no trouble exploding this and make use of the values with

```
sdf2 = sdf.select(sdf.zipcode, explode(sdf.employment_status))
sdf3 = sdf2.select(sdf2.zipcode, explode(sdf2.col))
sdf4 = sdf3.filter(sdf3.value != "Data").select(sdf3.zipcode, sdf3.value)
```

which results in the following:

```
sdf4:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
zipcode:string
value:string

+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|zipcode|value                                                                                                             |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|95678  |[{x=Full-time, y=13348}, {x=Part-time, y=8918}, {x=No Earnings, y=9972}]|
|95679  |[{x=Full-time, y=0}, {x=Part-time, y=29}, {x=No Earnings, y=0}]         |
|95680  |[{x=Full-time, y=43}, {x=Part-time, y=0}, {x=No Earnings, y=71}]        |
|95681  |[{x=Full-time, y=327}, {x=Part-time, y=265}, {x=No Earnings, y=278}]    |
|95682  |[{x=Full-time, y=8534}, {x=Part-time, y=6436}, {x=No Earnings, y=8748}] |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have a solution with F.regexp_extract and F.collect_list, but it feels not quit right.
The result should be the following

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|zipcode|full_employed|part_employed|non_employed|
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|  95678|        13348|         8918|        9972|
|  95679|            0|           29|           0|
|  95680|           43|            0|          71|
|  95681|          327|          265|         691|
|  95682|         8534|         6436|        8748|
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Or "Full-time", "Part-time" and "No earnings" as col- names, guess that doesn't matter.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so something like this?

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(sdf4
    .withColumn('y1', F.regexp_extract('value', 'y=([^}]+).*y=([^}]+).*y=([^}]+)', 1).cast('int'))
    .withColumn('y2', F.regexp_extract('value', 'y=([^}]+).*y=([^}]+).*y=([^}]+)', 2).cast('int'))
    .withColumn('y3', F.regexp_extract('value', 'y=([^}]+).*y=([^}]+).*y=([^}]+)', 3).cast('int'))

    .select('zipcode', F
        .expr('stack(1, y1, y2, y3)')
        .alias('full_employed','part_employed','non_employed')
    )
    .show()
)

# Output
# +-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
# |zipcode|full_employed|part_employed|non_employed|
# +-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
# |  95678|        13348|         8918|        9972|
# |  95679|            0|           29|           0|
# |  95680|           43|            0|          71|
# |  95681|          327|          265|         278|
# |  95682|         8534|         6436|        8748|
# +-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: How does your input df look like? on my end this produces only "NULL"


+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|zipcode|full_employed|part_employed|non_employed|
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|95678  |null         |null         |null        |
|95679  |null         |null         |null        |
|95680  |null         |null         |null        |
|95681  |null         |null         |null        |
|95682  |null         |null         |null        |
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+

Comment: This is what my df has: 

employment_status: array
element: map
key: string
value: string
and it is looking for a struct type...

Comment: I just updated my answer with sample input

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, my data looks a little different, just added to my question. As soon as I explode, my mapping is gone and I am left with a string. I can split that to get an array/str but then I am on the same track as before with regex to get values out of the string...

Comment: can you paste the result of `sdf.printSchema()`?

Comment: root
 |-- zipcode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employment_status: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

hard to read, I'll put it in the question..

Comment: I see, check my updated answer